# How to extract date and time parts from mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, max, datepart

I need to select a max(date) from a MySQL table and have each part of the date and time be in a separate variable.

Something like:

```
select max(date) as year, month, day, hour, minute, second from table
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
SELECT 
YEAR ( MAX(date) ) as year,
MONTH ( MAX(date) ) as month, 
DAY ( MAX(date) ) as day,
HOUR( MAX(date) ) as hour,
MINUTE( MAX(date) ) as minute,
SECOND( MAX(date) ) as second
from table
```